# Include location depending on server_name

Tags: nginx

I have a need to serve some static data only in a specific testing environment. I'm trying to do the following:

```
server {
    include listen;
    include listen_https;

    server_name myprodserver
    server_name mytestserver

    location / {
        do something here anyway
    }

    if ($server_name = "mytestserver") {
        location /loc/ {
            alias /usr/lib/myroot;
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error:

nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in mypath...

So how could I do it another way?

Comment: You can just make a new `server` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to the context in which nginx directives may or may not be used. You cannot use a `location` or `alias` directives within an `if` block. Additionaly, you need to check `$http_host` variable instead of `$server_name`. The only way I see without defining second `server` block is to define alternative root:

```
location /loc/ {
    if ($http_host = mytestserver) {
        root /usr/lib/myroot;
    }
}
```

and put your static files into `/usr/lib/myroot/loc/`.

Or, if you can rename `myroot` to `loc` (or vise versa):

```
location /loc/ {
    if ($http_host = mytestserver) {
        root /usr/lib;
    }
}
```